# How to programmatically check a Material-UI check-box?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's `Checkbox` component in my app, along with a related label.

I would like both the check-box and the label to be clickable, but I cannot use their `FormControlLabel` component (with `control` and `label` properties), which would ensure that clicking, because I want to use another component, instead of just text, for the label, and `FormControlLabel` doesn't seem to support it.

So, I'm thinking of triggering the click of the checbox when the label component gets clicked. Is there a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `Checkbox` with a regular `label` to make the label toggle the checkbox.

```
<label> Label <Checkbox/></label>;
```

You can also control the `Checkbox` by using a piece of state for the `checked` prop and toggle that programmatically.

```js
const { Checkbox } = window['material-ui'];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isChecked: false };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isChecked: !prevState.isChecked }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Checkbox checked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.toggle} />
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```